# parsing JSON file received by http multipart/form-data + hand over values (Java Springboot)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, multipartform-data

---

summary

- an upload service receives a stream of http multipart/form data containing a JSON (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
- the JSON values need to be handed over as parameters to a constructor

---

current situation: I will receive a http multipart/form-data from a REST API which contains a JSON file (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) by interface

```
@Override
public Mono<String> upload(String fileName, String mimeType, InputStream inputStream) throws UploadException {
        
}
```

let's assume the multipartfile posted will look like this (don't know the exact content yet):

```
POST http://123.4.5.6:78901/api/send HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="01ead4a5-4a67-53254-ad05-255485e25332"
Host: 123.4.5.6:78901
Content-Length: 100000


--01ead4a5-4a67-53254-ad05-255485e25332
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=printer


{
  "printerId": "123",
  "jobId": "456",
  "start": "2021-01-19 12:20:15,285",
  "optionalData": {
    "abc": "ABC",
    "def": "DEF",
    "ghi": "123"
  }
}
--01ead4a5-4a67-53254-ad05-255485e25332
```

the task now is to read the JSON values for each key and hand each value over as paramter to a constructor like

```
FileCmd fileCmd = new FileCmd(String printerId, String jobId, String start, Map<String, String> optionalData);
```

- I haven't been able to find an example that hands over JSON values from a multipart file as parameters or at least stores them in variables.
- iv'e also not been successful with Springboot, Jackson oder Apache Commons by now.

Is anyone able to give a hint how to proceed with this kind of task?

Answer (score 1):

Read the stream using **BufferReader**

```
BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = "";
```

Read every line and append it to **StringBuilder.**

```
StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while((line = bR.readLine()) != null){
   responseStrBuilder.append(line);
}
inputStream.close();
```

Finally pass the string object to **JSONObject**

```
JSONObject result= new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
```

To get the JSON value from the JSONObject:
**Example:**

```
String printerId = result.getString("printerId");
```